# Printer status for Mac

Tags: macos, printers

I need to know the Printer Status. I need to find the Printer Status of a printer connected via USB in Mac OSX. i got the print status using terminal code and implemented it inside the application using NSTask in 10.8, but its not working in 10.6. Please help me on this